# Creating youtube video slider in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, slider, carousel

I have a slider that shows videos form youtube. 
I basically use Carousel Slider and iframe, and everything looks normal. But the problem is that when I play a video and click on (Prev   Next) buttons the video will stay playing in the background. I have tried to fix that issue but nothing has worked for me yet.

My code looks like this:
Default.aspx

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1" />
<div class="ad-slider">
<div id="myCarousel1" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel1">
<!-- Carousel indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators" runat="server" id="ol1">

// indicators here   <---------------

</ol>
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner" runat="server" id="divVideo">

// Iframe contents here   <-----------------

</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" style="height:0px" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="prev">
<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" style="height:0px" href="#myCarousel1" data-slide="next">
<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
</a>
</div>
<!--end carousel-->
</div>
<!--end ad-slider-->
</div>
</div>
```

Then in code behind I have something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
if (i == 0)
{
ol1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<li data-target='#myCarousel1' data-slide-to='0' class='active'></li>"));
divVideo.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@" <div class='active item' > <iframe   src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/5wVfA9_S80Y'  style='width:100%;height:500px;border:0'  ></iframe></div>"));
}
else
{
ol1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<li data-target='#myCarousel1' data-slide-to='" + i.ToString() + "' ></li>"));
divVideo.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@" <div class='item' > <iframe  src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/5wVfA9_S80Y'  style='width:100%;height:500px;border:0'  ></iframe></div>"));
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me , what I have done so far is correct? and is there any way to prevent the video from playing in the background(or just stop it while clicking on next and prev buttons). Or may be there is a better way for doing this.